# Loosing Names when using Lapply

Tags: r, lapply, names

I want to do Chi-square tests on multiple variables **without using a loop**. 
As I want to store all the results, I have used the function `lapply`.

I need print the name of the columns and the names of the row that satisfy several conditions. 
However, when I used the function `lapply` the names are transformed into 1,2,3,4... However, I need to have the names instead of numbers. 
Here is my code:

```
dat1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(facturation$statut, facturation$OAL_SRC_IND, facturation$CPN_BKG_CLA))
colnames(dat1) <- c("statut", "OAL_SRC_IND", "CPN_BKG_CLA")
head(dat1)
res <- (lapply(names(dat1)[-1], function(x) CrossTable(dat1[,x], dat1[,"statut"], digits=2, format="SAS", expected=T, prop.t=F, prop.r=F, prop.c=F, prop.chisq=T, chisq=T, dnn=c(x, "statut"))))
```

I want the first output of my list to be this (with the names of the rows and columns):

Chisquare with names:
[image: Chisquare with names]

But when using the `lapply`, I get:

Chisquare without names:
[image: Chisquare without names]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide the data to make your code testable?